# python2.6 ubuntu 10.04‏‏

Tags: python, tinyos

I use ubuntu 10.04 and tinyos-2.1.1. I have a problem when i want run "make micaz sim".
The problem is the following :

```
mkdir -p simbuild/micaz
make: python2.6.5-config: Command not found
make: python2.6.5-config: Command not found
make: python2.6.5-config: Command not found
```

I try to update and install "python2.6-dev"

```
sudo apt-get install python2.6-dev
```

I add also

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/include/python2.6
```

I also modified in 'sim-fast.extra', 'sim-sf.extra' and 'sim.extra' files located in /support/make

```
PYTHON_VERSION=2.6.5
```

Have you any idea??
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the version to `2.6`, not `2.6.5`:

```
PYTHON_VERSION=2.6
```